# Memory problems in TypeORM, or me just filling it up

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

Have written an database init script in typescript using typeorm. And I seem to have cause a memory problem, but I can't figure out a way around it.

Currently the script imports three files
Profiles (55 records)
User (5306 records)
Logins (1006909 records)

Rewrote the calls so in all cases, the script will create a JSON with all the updates, then use `createQueryBuilder` to execute the update as per below:

```
getConnection()
                                    .createQueryBuilder()
                                    .insert()
                                    .into(EULogin)
                                    .values(loginChunk)
                                    .execute()
                                    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Works a charm for the first ones, but when it comes to the last one (the 1,000,000 entires), it will not play ball. And I get a memory problem

> LOGIN: Committed 196000/1006909 (Chunk Size:500) to database in 155 MS
> LOGIN: Committed 196500/1006909 (Chunk Size:500) to database in 823 MS
>
> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [60698:0x110008000]    34328 ms: Scavenge 1389.1 (1423.6) -> 1388.6
> (1423.6) MB, 12.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.104, current mu = 0.099)
> allocation failure  [60698:0x110008000]    34339 ms: Scavenge 1389.3
> (1423.6) -> 1388.9 (1423.6) MB, 10.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.104,
> current mu = 0.099) allocation failure  [60698:0x110008000]    34361
> ms: Scavenge 1389.4 (1423.6) -> 1389.1 (1424.1) MB, 12.5 / 0.0 ms
> (average mu = 0.104, current mu = 0.099) allocation failure
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> ```
> 0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x20ed7445be3d]
> 1: StubFrame [pc: 0x20ed7440d608]
> 2: StubFrame [pc: 0x20ed7502c4cc] Security context: 0x0fbfb411e6e9 <JSObject>
> 3: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [0xfbf79c62a41] [/Users/bengtbjorkberg/Development/EUGrapherNode/node_modules/typeorm/query-builder/InsertQueryBuilder.js:348]
> ```
>
> [bytecode=0xfbf93b851a1 offset=26](this=0x0fbfab4826f1
> ,valueSet=0x0fbf8846ebc1 <Object map = 0xfbfbf7...
>
> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation
> failed - JavaScript heap out of memory  1: 0x10003cf99 node::Abort()
> [/usr/local/bin/node]  2: 0x10003d1a3 node::OnFatalError(char const*,
> char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]  3: 0x1001b7835
> v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
> const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]  4: 0x100585682
> v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*)
> [/usr/local/bin/node]  5: 0x100588155
> v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double)
> [/usr/local/bin/node]  6: 0x100583fff
> v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector,
> v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]  7: 0x1005821d4
> v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace,
> v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags)
> [/usr/local/bin/node]  8: 0x10058ea6c
> v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLigthRetry(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
> [/usr/local/bin/node]  9: 0x10058eaef
> v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
> [/usr/local/bin/node] 10: 0x10055e434
> v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool,
> v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/usr/local/bin/node] 11: 0x1007e6714
> v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**,
> v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node] 12: 0x20ed7445be3d
>
> Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

I have tried to open the database in synchronous mode (not async)
I have tried to split the last update in as small as 50 records at a time
I even tried to open and close the database for each chunk, but that died because I could not get it to do so synchronously.

Opening the database with:

```
createConnection().then(connection => {
```

And below is the "Chunkloader"

```
.on('end', () => {
                            let compTime: number = new Date().getTime()
                            console.log("LOGIN: Entities read: " + loginReadCounter + " in " + new Date(compTime - loginStartTime).getMilliseconds() + " MS")
                            let currentChunk :number = 0;
                            let chunkSize : number = 500;
                            let loginChunk = [];
                            let loginStartChunkTime : number = compTime;
                            loginEntries.forEach(entry => {
                                loginChunk.push(entry);
                                currentChunk ++;
                                loginCommitCounter++;
                                if (currentChunk === chunkSize !! ){
                                    getConnection()
                                        .createQueryBuilder()
                                        .insert()
                                        .into(EULogin)
                                        .values(loginChunk)
                                        .execute()
                                        .catch(error => console.log(error))

                                    let compTime: number = new Date().getTime()
                                    console.log("LOGIN: Committed "  + loginCommitCounter + "/" + loginReadCounter + " (Chunk Size:" + loginChunk.length + ") to database in " + new Date(compTime - loginStartChunkTime).getMilliseconds() + " MS");
                                    currentChunk = 0;
                                    loginStartChunkTime = compTime;
                                    loginChunk = [];

                                }
                            });
```

Any ideas?

========================== EDIT FOLLOWING GOOD INPUT ====================

To try to sort my own head out, I moved it to a separate function, I got `await` to work, but how do I stop the process from continuing after the call. Because await works inside createConnection, but it does not work on createConnection, so the function will return straight away

```
function syncDataWrite(dbEntitiy, dataSet){
    console.log("DBLOADER Started for: " + dataSet.length);
    createConnection().then(async connection => {
        console.log("DBLOADER Connected!");
        const completion = await createQueryBuilder()
            .insert()
            .into(dbEntitiy)
            .values(dataSet)
            .execute()
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
            console.log("DBLOADER SQL uploaded")
    })
    // console.log(dbEntity);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code suggests that, while you chunk things, you are executing *everything* in parallel, which is probably not what you want.

I'd recommend you rewrite this to properly put this in sequence.

The easiest by far will be to switch to async/await and use a regular `for` loop. Assuming `.execute()` returns a promise, this would look something like this:

```
const connection = getConnection();
for (const entry of loginEntries) {
   // [snip]  
   await createQueryBuilder()
     .insert()
     .into(EULogin)
     .values(loginChunk)
     .execute()
   // [snip]
}
```

I stripped a bunch of your code, but I hope this general setup still makes sense.

It's possible to do this without async/await, but it's going to look a whole lot more complicated.

**Edit based on your edit**.

Here's a rewritten version of `syncDataWrite`:

```js
async function syncDataWrite(dbEntitiy, dataSet){

    console.log("DBLOADER Started for: " + dataSet.length);
    const connection = await createConnection();
    console.log("DBLOADER Connected!");
    const completion = await createQueryBuilder()
       .insert()
       .into(dbEntitiy)
       .values(dataSet)
       .execute();

}
```

Note that if you use `syncDataWrite` multiple times, 1 for each chunk, you need to still `await` syncDataWrite when it's called.

Comment: Been trying this, but can't get it to work. As soon as I run it I get an `Error:(170, 37) TS1308: 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.`. Not certain if it is because I am doing it from the fs stream or something. But it looks like it is running it synchronously

Comment: Added a function in the end, and you are right, but I can't get await working even in that (I think) simple example

Comment: @vrghost if `syncDataWrite` only handles a single chunk, then you still have the exact same problem. You need to use `await syncDataWrite()`.

You can also do `const connection = await getConnection()`

Answer (score 0):

I took a lot of problem to fix this performance issue,
at the end of the day I got it working using repository, instead of queryBuilder.

Before:

```
ActiveRentalEntity.createQueryBuilder('ar')
  .insert()
  .values(data)
  .execute()
```

After (using repository). It's not because of the chunk thing, I tried chunking it manually using query builder and got same problem, seems like repository is better optmized:

```
getRepository(ActiveRentalEntity).save(data, { chunk: 1000 });
```